Parse Rule Correctly via Excel Macro
Excel Tab Name: Rule
Cell A1 contains this rule.
"DSO_90Day"->"FA_NoFunc"->"FCCS_No Intercompany"->"FCCS_Data Input"->"FCCS_No Movement"->"NoCC"->"FCCS_YTD_Input"  = (("TradeAR"->"Total Functional Area"->"FCCS_Intercompany Top"->"FCCS_Total Data Source"->"FCCS_Movements"->"Total Business Unit"->"FCCS_Periodic" - "TradeARTooling"->"Total Functional Area"->"FCCS_Intercompany Top"->"FCCS_Total Data Source"->"FCCS_Movements"->"Total Business Unit"->"FCCS_Periodic"  + "AllowDbtflAcc"->"Total Functional Area"->"FCCS_Intercompany Top"->"FCCS_Total Data Source"->"FCCS_Movements"->"Total Business Unit"->"FCCS_Periodic" ) / ("NetSalesTwoMthsPrior"->"Total Functional Area"->"FCCS_Intercompany Top"->"FCCS_Total Data Source"->"FCCS_Movements"->"Total Business Unit"->"FCCS_Periodic" + "NetSalesCurrent"->"Total Functional Area"->"FCCS_Intercompany Top"->"FCCS_Total Data Source"->"FCCS_Movements"->"Total Business Unit"->"FCCS_Periodic" + "NetSalesPrior"->"Total Functional Area"->"FCCS_Intercompany Top"->"FCCS_Total Data Source"->"FCCS_Movements"->"Total Business Unit"->"FCCS_Periodic")) * 90;

I'm trying to parse this rule dynamically (see more examples of rules at the bottom) with this Macro and get it into this format within a tab called SmartView.
Expected output

Sub ParseRule()
    Dim ruleSheet As Worksheet
    Dim smartViewSheet As Worksheet
    Dim rule As String
    Dim parts() As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim cellValue As Variant
    Dim operators As String
    Dim currentRow As Integer
    Dim currentCol As Integer
    Dim members() As String
    Dim remainingRule As String
    Dim operatorFound As Boolean
    Dim nextOperatorIndex As Integer
    Dim nextOperator As String
    
    ' Define the sheets
    Set ruleSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Rule")
    Set smartViewSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SmartView")
    
    ' Clear previous content in SmartView sheet
    smartViewSheet.Cells.Clear
    
    ' Get the rule from A1 in Rule sheet
    rule = ruleSheet.Range("A1").Value
    
    ' Replace all double quotes with empty string
    rule = Replace(rule, """", "")
    
    ' Define operators to split the rule
    operators = "=+-*/()"
    
    ' Initialize starting row and column
    currentRow = 1
    currentCol = 1
    
    ' Initialize remainingRule with the rule
    remainingRule = rule
    
    ' Loop through the rule
    Do While Len(remainingRule) > 0
        ' Find the next operator and its position
        operatorFound = False
        nextOperatorIndex = Len(remainingRule) + 1
        nextOperator = ""
        
        For i = 1 To Len(operators)
            Dim op As String
            op = Mid(operators, i, 1)
            
            Dim pos As Integer
            pos = InStr(remainingRule, op)
            
            ' Check if the operator is "-" and if it's not part of "->"
            If op = "-" Then
                Dim nextArrow As String
                nextArrow = "->"
                If InStr(remainingRule, nextArrow) = 0 Then
                    If pos > 0 And pos < nextOperatorIndex Then
                        nextOperatorIndex = pos
                        nextOperator = op
                        operatorFound = True
                    End If
                End If
            Else
                If pos > 0 And pos < nextOperatorIndex Then
                    nextOperatorIndex = pos
                    nextOperator = op
                    operatorFound = True
                End If
            End If
        Next i
        
        ' Process the part before the next operator
        If nextOperatorIndex > 1 Then
            parts = Split(Left(remainingRule, nextOperatorIndex - 1), ">")
            For Each cellValue In parts
                smartViewSheet.Cells(currentRow, currentCol).Value = Trim(cellValue)
                currentCol = currentCol + 1
            Next cellValue
        End If
        
        ' Process the operator
        If operatorFound Then
            smartViewSheet.Cells(currentRow, currentCol).Value = nextOperator
            currentRow = currentRow + 1
            currentCol = 1
        End If
        
        ' Move to the remaining part of the rule
        remainingRule = Mid(remainingRule, nextOperatorIndex + 1)
    Loop
    
    ' Handle any remaining part after the last operator
    If Len(remainingRule) > 0 Then
        parts = Split(remainingRule, ">")
        For Each cellValue In parts
            smartViewSheet.Cells(currentRow, currentCol).Value = Trim(cellValue)
            currentCol = currentCol + 1
        Next cellValue
    End If
End Sub

However, I'm close but no cigar.  Could use another pair of eyes on this.
Current Results

NOTE: Trying to build a dynamic macro as the rule format will change...here are other examples...
"NetSalesPrior" = @PRIOR("FCCS_Sales"->"Total Functional Area"->"FCCS_Intercompany Top"->"FCCS_Total Data Source"->"FCCS_Movements"->"Total Business Unit");

Expected Results
 "COSTotalTwoMthsPrior" = "Sep"->"COSTotal"->"Total Functional Area"->"FCCS_Intercompany Top"->"FCCS_Total Data Source"->"FCCS_Movements"->"Total Business Unit";

Expected Results
 "PRDPUR" = "PURTOT"->"Total Functional Area"->"FCCS_Intercompany Top"->"FCCS_Total Data Source"->"FCCS_Movements"->"Total Business Unit" + "PRDINV"->"Total Functional Area"->"FCCS_Intercompany Top"->"FCCS_Total Data Source"->"FCCS_Movements"->"Total Business Unit" - @PRIOR("PRDINV"->"Total Functional Area"->"FCCS_Intercompany Top"->"FCCS_Total Data Source"->"FCCS_Movements"->"Total Business Unit");

Expected Results
In summary, I'm trying to get all operators separate to the right including any functions (i.e anything that starts with @).  All Account Members are placed from Col A through however many columns needed.  There's always an empty column between Accounts and the Operators/Functions.
Dynamic Script based on Taller's script...
Sub GenerateRegExpPattern()
    Dim ruleSheet As Worksheet
    Dim smartViewSheet As Worksheet
    Dim rule As String
    Dim pattern As String

    On Error Resume Next
    Set ruleSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Rule")
    Set smartViewSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SmartView")
    On Error GoTo 0

    If ruleSheet Is Nothing Or smartViewSheet Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Please ensure that both 'Rule' and 'SmartView' sheets exist.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    smartViewSheet.Cells.Clear

    ' Get the rule from the "Rule" tab, assuming it starts at cell A1
    rule = ruleSheet.Range("A1").Value
    
    ' Remove double quotes
    rule = Replace(rule, Chr(34), "")
    
    ' Generate the regex pattern based on the rule
    pattern = GeneratePattern(rule)
    
    ' Output the pattern to the "SmartView" tab, cell A1
    smartViewSheet.Range("A1").Value = pattern

    ' Call the ParseRule_WithPattern subroutine with the generated pattern
    ParseRule_WithPattern pattern, rule
End Sub

Function GeneratePattern(rule As String) As String
    Dim pattern As String
    Dim elements As Variant
    Dim element As Variant
    Dim operatorChars As String

    ' Define the characters that are considered operators
    operatorChars = "=+-*/"

    ' Split the rule by spaces to handle different parts
    elements = Split(rule, " ")

    ' Construct the regex pattern
    For Each element In elements
        If InStr(1, operatorChars, element) > 0 Then
            ' Add operator to the pattern
            pattern = pattern & "\s*" & Replace(element, "+", "\+") & "\s*"
        ElseIf IsNumeric(element) Then
            ' Add number to the pattern
            pattern = pattern & "\d+"
        ElseIf InStr(element, "->") > 0 Then
            ' Handle repeated groups indicated by "->"
            Dim groupPattern As String
            Dim parts() As String
            parts = Split(element, "->")
            
            If UBound(parts) > 0 Then
                ' Generate pattern for repeated groups
                groupPattern = "([\w\s]+->)+" & parts(UBound(parts))
            Else
                ' If no repetition, treat as single group
                groupPattern = "[\w\s]+->[\w\s]+"
            End If
            
            pattern = pattern & groupPattern
        Else
            ' Add any other word or space character to the pattern
            pattern = pattern & "[\w\s]+"
        End If
    Next element

    ' Set the pattern as the result
    GeneratePattern = pattern
    Debug.Print "Generated Pattern: " & pattern
End Function

Sub ParseRule_WithPattern(pattern As String, rule As String)
    Dim ruleSheet As Worksheet
    Dim smartViewSheet As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, iR As Long
    Dim aTxt() As String, strMatch As String, arrRes() As Variant
    Dim objRegExp As Object, objMatch As Object

    Set ruleSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Rule")
    Set smartViewSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SmartView")

    ' Remove double quotes
    rule = Replace(rule, Chr(34), "")
    
    Set objRegExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    objRegExp.pattern = pattern
    objRegExp.Global = True
    objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
    objRegExp.MultiLine = False

    ' Debugging output
    Debug.Print "Rule: " & rule
    Debug.Print "Pattern: " & pattern

    On Error GoTo RegexError
    Set objMatch = objRegExp.Execute(rule)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If objMatch.Count > 0 Then ' matching is found
        ' Determine the number of columns needed
        Dim maxCols As Long
        maxCols = 0
        For j = 0 To objMatch.Count - 1
            strMatch = objMatch(j).SubMatches(0)
            aTxt = Split(strMatch, "->")
            If UBound(aTxt) + 2 > maxCols Then maxCols = UBound(aTxt) + 2
        Next

        ' Prepare the results array
        ReDim arrRes(1 To objMatch.Count, 1 To maxCols)
        
        ' Populate the results array
        For j = 0 To objMatch.Count - 1
            strMatch = objMatch(j).SubMatches(0)
            aTxt = Split(strMatch, "->")
            iR = iR + 1
            For i = 0 To UBound(aTxt)
                arrRes(iR, i + 1) = Trim(aTxt(i))
            Next
            ' operator
            arrRes(iR, UBound(aTxt) + 2) = objMatch(j).SubMatches(1)
            ' last digit
            If Len(objMatch(j).SubMatches(2)) > 0 Then
                arrRes(iR + 1, UBound(aTxt) + 2) = objMatch(j).SubMatches(2)
            End If
        Next

        ' Debugging output
        Debug.Print "Array dimensions: " & UBound(arrRes, 1) & "x" & UBound(arrRes, 2)
        
        ' Ensure the array is properly dimensioned and populated
        If Not IsEmpty(arrRes) Then
            smartViewSheet.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arrRes, 1), UBound(arrRes, 2)).Value = arrRes
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "No matches found for the pattern.", vbInformation
    End If
    Exit Sub

RegexError:
    Debug.Print "Regex Error: " & Err.Description
    MsgBox "An error occurred while executing the regex pattern. Please check the pattern and rule format.", vbCritical
End Sub



Using RegExp is a more efficient method for extracting the desired data.

Microsoft documentation:

Range.Resize property (Excel)


Split function


Replace function

Option Explicit
Sub ParseRule()
    Dim ruleSheet As Worksheet
    Dim smartViewSheet As Worksheet
    Dim rule As String
    Set ruleSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Rule")
    Set smartViewSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SmartView")
    smartViewSheet.Cells.Clear
    ' remove double quote
    rule = Replace(ruleSheet.Range("A1").Value, Chr(34), "")
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, iR As Long
    Dim aTxt, strMatch As String, arrRes
    Dim objRegExp As Object, objMatch As Object
    Set objRegExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    objRegExp.Pattern = "((?:[\w ]+->){6}[\w]+)[\s)]*([=+\-*/])\s([\d]+)*"
    objRegExp.Global = True
    objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
    objRegExp.MultiLine = False
    Set objMatch = objRegExp.Execute(rule)    
    If objMatch.Count > 0 Then ' matching is found
        ' an extra row for last digits, two extra cols for operators
        ReDim arrRes(1 To objMatch.Count + 1, UBound(Split(objMatch(0).submatches(0), "->")) + 2)
        For j = 0 To objMatch.Count - 1
            strMatch = objMatch(j).submatches(0)
            ' split and populate Col A to Col G
            aTxt = Split(strMatch, "->")
            iR = iR + 1
            For i = 0 To UBound(aTxt)
                arrRes(iR, i) = Trim(aTxt(i))
            Next
            ' operator
            arrRes(iR, i + 1) = objMatch(j).submatches(1)
            ' last digit
            If Len(objMatch(j).submatches(2)) > 0 Then
                arrRes(iR + 1, i + 1) = objMatch(j).submatches(2)
            End If
        Next
    End If
    ' write output to sheet
    smartViewSheet.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arrRes, 1), UBound(arrRes, 2) + 1).Value = arrRes
End Sub

Note:

The RegExp is only validated on the sample data provided in the original post. You may need to revise it if your actual data follows a different pattern.


Like you said, this is great for the rule format I provided originally, but I was trying to build something more dynamic.  I provided more examples at the bottom of the post.

What is the the best way to ask follow up questions? It is helpful to share what's the expected output for sample data set.

I provided the expected results at the end of the post.  Thanks!

I tried building the pattern based on any format of the rule but no luck.  So I used your script as the base but added to it.  I've update the post with what I'm using.  If you could lend a pair of eyes, I think this will get us the dynamic solution.

What is the the best way to ask follow up questions? I would suggest rollback the question and post a new followup question.
